# private_key argument is deprecated Google Cloud

Tags: airflow

Hi Currently getting the following error in airflow using airflow HELM.

Any ideas on this?

`The private_key argument is deprecated. Construct a credentials object, instead, by using the google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file or google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info class method from the google-auth package.`